# Refreshing images on page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script to update images on a page displaying webcams. The webcam images are pulled by FTP. Because I want to implement a filtering interface, using mixitup, I don't want the whole page to refresh as this will clear any filters.

The images mostly refresh every 10 seconds, however they keep flickering back to old pictures. Almost like some caching issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function imgRefresh() {
    var now = new Date();
    for(i=0; i<document.images.length; i++) {
        document.images[i].src= document.images[i].src.split("?")[0];
        document.images[i].src = document.images[i].src + "?"+now.getTime();
    }
    setTimeout('imgRefresh()', 5*1000);
}

</script>
```

Cheers!